# Remote Desktop Services error on WS 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, remote-desktop, windows-server-2012-r2

I have Remote Desktop Services running on Windows Server 2012 R2. This feature is still working just fine. I can log into the RD Web page, and access all of my remote applications that I have published.

However, I can no longer manage the deployment. When I launch server manager, and navigate to Remote Desktop Services, I see a message "A Remote Desktop Services deployment does not exist in the server pool. To create a deployment, run the Add Roles and Features Wizard and select the Remote Desktop Services installation option."

When I click manage > Add Roles and Features. The RD Web components are showing as installed. This just started happening recently. Does anyone know why?

[image]

Comment: I did some testing today. I removed all of the Remote Desktop Services Features, then rebooted. I attempted a reinstall of the same features following this article (http://www.concurrency.com/blog/w/rds8-quick-and-easy,-remoteapp-on-windows-server-2).                                                                                This article attempts a scenario based installation, but I got an error about server compatibility problems and was forced to exclude the server.

Comment: When I chose Role based installation. I was able to reinstall all of the components again, but got the same original error as before.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it! I'm not sure why this fixed it, but disabling the options for IPv6 worked. Basically, go into your NIC adapter properties, and uncheck the box next to IPv6.

Comment: Same here; I was hoping to avoid rebooting the server so figured I'd give it a shot, and low and behold, this fixed it for me too!  :amazed: